# How to focus on next field after selecting Selectize.js field

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

How can I focus to next element after I select an item from `selectize.js` `select` element ? I did not find onSelect option in selectize.js. Note:my next element is also selectize.js select element

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `change` event on first select-box . Then , whenever first-select box gets change use instance of selectize and call `.focus()` for second select-box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var $select = $('#a').selectize();
var $select2 = $('#b').selectize();
// get instance
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
var selectize2 = $select2[0].selectize;
//on change of first select or use blur event
selectize.on('change', function onChange() {
  selectize2.focus() //focus second one 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<select id="a">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="3">N</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="22">Ar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I found '`onChange :`' function inside selectize like `$('#a').selectize({ onChange: function() { $("#b")[0].selectize.focus(); } })` . This is also working as expected. Thanks anyway.